# How to set celery result backend key before task function runs?

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm using multiple databases in my django project(redis, postgresql). In celery, I'm running a task function with the countdown parameter set to a week which put the results in redis result backend. Then i'm trying to save the redis key in postresql table. If I set the redis key before task function runs, I can access the redis record later. So, Is there a way to do that? (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
result = add.apply_async(countdown=time_in_seconds)
result.id #give you task id.
```

You can save it now to your postgres.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that celery key and task function id are the same. Thank you :)